# Is there an algorithm or theory that points out far extreme outliers?

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, descriptive-statistics

When doing a density plot, histogram or box plot I noticed that outliers are somewhat easy to identify. However is there a proper concept on how to measure outliers based on how far it is from being a really bad outlier?

Comment: Not really. Outliers are to be determined not based on statistics but knowledge of the data and its issues

Comment: Outliers are data points that are unusual extreme based on the hypothesized family of distributions. You describe what is too extreme. Some people view outliers as being errors but that is not necessarily the case. It is possible that you just observed a value from a tail of the hypothesized distribution. There are many tests for outliers. Dixon's ratio test and Grubbs' test are two examples. I discuss this in more detail on other threads on this site.

Comment: The book by Vic Barnett and Toby Lewis is a large volume solely on outliers.

Comment: If you're working with histograms, you can also check HBOS: https://www.dfki.de/KI2012/PosterDemoTrack/ki2012pd13.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a somewhat old-school algorithm (now at least) that can be used to find outliers. It's called the Minimum Convariance Determinant (MCD) algorithm. Here's is a [paper](http://www.geo.upm.es/postgrado/CarlosLopez/papers/FastAlgMCD99.pdf) on the subject - but there may be more recent research on the algorithm. There is also an implementation in [Scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.covariance.MinCovDet.html).

Some images because they are pretty and informative (from [here](https://tr8dr.wordpress.com/2010/09/24/minimum-covariance-determination/)):

[image: img]

Comment: I think the OP was only addressing univariate outliers. Another method for determining multivariate outliers is the use of influence functions.

Comment: is influence function an r/python module?

Answer (score 0):

Projection pursuit methods have been proposed for outlier detection: http://www.utdallas.edu/~serfling/papers/Mazumder_Serfling_Dec_2011.PDF

Cook's distance is also useful, but only in the context of regression analysis.

But in general, as pointed out, prior knowledge of the data and the context is essential.